# increment and assign variable value in python pandas dataframe if condition is true; not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am very new to python and having difficulty using DF's

i have this code:

```
class Visualize():
def __init__(self, band, startFreq, endFreq):
    self.band = band
    self.startFreq = startFreq
    self.endFreq = endFreq
    self.max_stage = 0

//increments max_stage value
def incrStage(self):
    self.max_stage = self.max_stage+1
    return self.max_stage
    
    
def getVisualize(self):
    self.band = self.band.sort_values("TX_FREQ")            
    
    self.band['stage'] = np.where(self.band['lower'] < self.band['upper'].shift(), self.incrStage(), 0 )
    
    self.band['difference'] = self.band['lower'] - self.band['upper'].shift()
    
    return self.band
```

now i want to create a "stage" column which has the incremented value when i see that row[x]['lower'] < row[x-1]['upper']

max_stage starts with 0
and everytime the condition is true i want max_stage to be "++max_stage" and the value to be set into "stage" column.

i have the code in getVisualize() function but it returns this data set with only "1" as the value:

[image: here]

Comment: There's no `++max_stage` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @GuyIncognito i had to create a remedy because ++ operator is not in python. but ++i is what i want to do and its not working either which ever way i do it
max_stage+1 doesnt work either neither max_stage+=1
i have editied the title to be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `np.where()` only calls your function `incrStage()` once. It is called once and its return value is used anywhere your condition is True.

The easiest would be to do something like this:

```
self.band['stage'] = [self.incrStage() if x else 0 for x in self.band['lower'] < self.band['upper'].shift()]
```

This runs like in a for loop and thus calls your function anywhere the condition is True.

BTW: The syntax for incrementing a variable would be `self.max_stage += 1`.

Comment: Thankyou!
yes that was the problem that the function was only being called once.

this is very confusing in python and being a newbie always gets the best of me.

thankyou for the help!